# Honorific Verbs conjugation - ～ていらっしゃる vs お + Verb Stem + になる

Tags: verbs, conjugations, て-form, honorifics

In book "Genki II", there's no explanation for verbs that **don't have a special** conjugation, for when to conjugate either to:

1. 「て Form」 + いらっしゃる
2. お + Verb Stem + になる

My simple question is when to use the 1st type and when to use the other?

Or do I have the option to select the conjugation for verbs that don't have the special conjugation?

For example:

読む　ー＞

- お読みになる
- 読んでいらっしゃる

Comment: What is the difference between 読む and 読んでいる?

Comment: One is the short form and the other the ～て Form of the verb use for an action that is happening for continues of time (like present progressive). 
How is that relevant to my question?
Can you please elaborate on your question?

Comment: じゃ「読んでいらっしゃる」と「お読みになっている」を比べてみたら・・

Answer (score 1):

If you read it carefully in Genki II て＋いらっしゃる is the honorific form for the て＋いる verb format. Whereas you would use お＋verb stem＋になる when it is not a continuing action.

Comment: Now I get it.

The book doesn't explicitly state the difference in their usage. It gives a blank list-table at first and then represents the 2 ways to conjugate non-special verbs with a vague explanation between the 2.